# How can I copy from recordset with headers?

Tags: excel, vba, recordset

I am trying to use ActiveCell.CopyFromRecordset on recordset to copy recordset with headers. I am trying to get rid of saving recordset result to variable before putting it into excel.
Is there a way to inject a row with headers before copy?
Or can it be done by creating custom class that immitates recordset?

```vb
Public Function RecordSet(Optional ByVal QueryString As Variant, Optional ByVal UseLast As Variant = True) As ADODB.RecordSet
    Dim qstr As String
    If IsMissing(QueryString) = False Then
        qstr = QueryString
    ElseIf Me.SavedQuery <> "" And UseLast = True Then
        qstr = Me.SavedQuery
    Else
        qstr = Me.QUERY(UseLast:=UseLast)
    End If
    Call Me.Connect
    sqlrs.Open qstr, sqlcon

    Set RecordSet = sqlrs
    sqlrs.Close
End Function

Dim rs As ADODB.RecordSet
Set rs = RecordSet
For i = 0 To RecordSet.Fields.Count - 1
    MsgBox rs.Fields(i).Name
Next
ActiveCell.CopyFromRecordset RecordSet
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this might help you have the headers at top. First row will be filled by header names. CopyFromRecordset will fill all the remaning data starting from 2nd row.

```
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    Cells(1,i+1).Value= rs.Fields(i).Name
Next
Cells(2,1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Comment: I know that, buy I am trying to avoid having to complete transfer so I would like add headers before that so I can keep the stream open.

Comment: Then i did not understand the question, still.

Comment: Do cell formattings get passed over to excel via copyfromrecordset? In this case what I want would not be a good idea. What I wanted is to get column names together with copyfromrecordset.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the copyfromrecordset first.  Then insert a row above it using vba.  Then put in the headers.  That would preserve the formatting you get on the copy.

Comment: Please improve your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer has more information. Thanks.